# encrypt and decrypt the file using tripleDES

Tags: c#

Can someone give me the code or valuable sugestion to Encrypt and Decrypt a large file in C#?
 I'm trying to do this with TripleDES.it should be safe,fast and reliable
here the encryption and decryption should done based on my key.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the piece of code if anybody else is looking for it.

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plain, String key)
    {
        byte[] keyArray = SoapHexBinary.Parse(key).Value;

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        tdes.IV = new byte[8];

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length);
        tdes.Clear();

        return resultArray;
    }


    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipher, String key)
    {
        byte[] keyArray = SoapHexBinary.Parse(key).Value;

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        tdes.IV = new byte[8];

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
        tdes.Clear();

        return resultArray;
    }
```

Keep in mind that I was passing key as in HexBinary format. Above code uses CBC cipher mode with initial vector { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0} and padding is set to None because data I was passing in was always multiple of 64 bit. Therefore If your data size is not fixed then you may need to set the padding.